# Blank space above centered text in tabularx

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a problem in my report with tabularx and center... I try to center the content of some columns but I don't know why, is there a blank space above the centered text...

Here is my code

```
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{4cm}|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
& \center{Rest. IN} & \center{Rest. OUT} & \center{Ouvrier} & \center{Compta.} & \center\arraybackslash{Ress. hum.} \\
S'arranger avec le manager du restaurant IN & x & x & & & \\
Donner son accord & x & x & & & \\
Attendre le jour convenu & & & x & & \\             
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blank space results from an incorrect syntax for your attempt at centering content.

For regular centering inside a specific cell, you can use `\centering`. For column-wide alignment, you can redefine the way the `X`-column works via something like

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
```

If you're intermixing regular `X`-column and centered `X`-column alignment often, you can define a new `X`-column type using

```
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X{#1}}
```

This creates `Y` to be the same as `X`, except it inserts `\centering\arraybackslash` into the cell before setting its contents.

Here's a approach using the former:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabulax
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{4cm}|X|X|X|X|X|}
  \hline
  & \centering Rest. IN & \centering Rest. OUT & \centering Ouvrier & \centering Compta. & \centering\arraybackslash Ress. hum. \\
  S'arranger avec le manager du restaurant IN & x & x & & & \\
  Donner son accord & x & x & & & \\
  Attendre le jour convenu & & & x & & \\             
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

These alignment styles are paragraph-based. So, using `\centering` inside an `l` or `r` column would not work. However, since an `X`-column is defined as `m`-column (which is essentially a `p`-column), `\centering` works fine.

Comment: Thank you. And is it possible to create a new kind of column which would be like a centered X ? I ask that because I have other tabularx in which I don't want to center my X columns.

Comment: @DescampsAu: Yes. As I mention at the start of my answer, you can redefine the way the `X`-column works via manipulating the macro `\tabularxcolumn`. By default, `\tabularxcolumn` is defined using `\newcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{p{#1}}`, but you can modify this to be `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}`. Since this may be specific to some `tabularx` construction in your document, perform the renewal of `\tabularxcolumn` inside a group that surrounds the `tabularx` in question. See p 3 of http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf.

Comment: I tried : \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} but it doesn't work :s

Comment: I get it : \newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X{#1}}
It works even if I don't really understand why...